# getting a responseLength for a HttpWebRequest upload from another webfile to stream into the upload when the source doesn't implement ContentLength?

Tags: httpwebrequest, streaming, httpwebresponse, http-content-length

**Background** - I'm trying to stream an existing webpage to a separate web application, using HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse in C#.  One issue I'm striking is that I'm trying to set the file upload request content-length using the file download's content-length, HOWEVER the issue seems to be when the source webpage is on a webserver for which the HttpWebResponse doesn't provide a content length.

```
HttpWebRequest downloadRequest = WebRequest.Create(new Uri("downloaduri")) as HttpWebRequest;
 using (HttpWebResponse downloadResponse = downloadRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
 {
   var uploadRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(new Uri("uripath"));
   uploadRequest.Method = "POST";
   uploadRequest.ContentLength = downloadResponse.ContentLength;  // ####
```

**QUESTION**: How could I update this approach to cater for this case (when the download response doesn't have a content-length set).  Would it be to somehow use a MemoryStream perhaps?  Any sample code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy to download the response from the other web server completely, that would indeed make life easier. Just repeatedly write into a MemoryStream as you fetch from the first web server, then you know the length to set for the second request and you can write the data in easily (especially as `MemoryStream` has a [`WriteTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.writeto.aspx) method to write its contents to another stream).

The downside of this is that you'll take a lot of memory if it's a large file. Is that likely to be a problem in your situation? Alternatives include:

- Writing to a file instead of using a `MemoryStream`. You'll need to clean up the file afterwards, of course - you're basically using the file system as bigger memory :)
- Using a chunked transfer encoding to "read a chunk, write a chunk"; this *may* be fiddly to get right - it's certainly not something I've done before.

Comment: The chunked approach sounds interesting.  Anyone know if HttpWebRequest supports this?  Is this the default behavior for an upload if you don't set the content length?

Comment: @Greg: I'm not sure, to be honest - I suggest you experiment :)